# Firebase authentication mails go to spam folder every time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app which is available on Google play store. My app uses firebase authenticator for email verification. But every time, the mails are going to spam folder. I can not use any paid verification service because my app does not support the api system.
Is there any solution to recover from this problem?

I did not find any solution of this problem. I am seeking for help.